# Upgrading 11.10 gives: libcurl3-gnutls, libp11-kit0 - Dependency error

Tags: 11.10, dependencies

When i do upgrade or install, im getting this error.

```
srikanth@btp8sa42:~/projects/raff$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for srikanth: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl3-gnutls : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.3 is installed
               Depends: libgnutls26 (>= 2.12.6.1-0) but 2.10.5-1ubuntu3.2 is installed
               Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~) but 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.3 is installed
 libp11-kit0 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

When i do "apt-get -f install"

```
srikanth@btp8sa42:~/projects/raff$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl3-gnutls : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.3 is installed
               Depends: libgnutls26 (>= 2.12.6.1-0) but 2.10.5-1ubuntu3.2 is installed
               Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~) but 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.3 is installed
 libp11-kit0 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.3 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: This question may help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: @ChrisCarter No, not a duplicate. That question seems to be about a different error. In this case he seems to have put some packages on hold. Srikanth should provide a list of all held packages (can someone give the right ˋdpkgˋ command for that?).

Comment: List of all held packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/526634/libcurl3-gnutls-libp11-kit0-dependency-error/526650) has solved the problem.

Doing a

```
apt-get install libp11-kit0/oneiric libcurl3-gnutls/oneiric
```

fixed this.